# *.r files in website

Tags: r, web

I have a requirement to allow users to download *.r extension files. These are used for statistical analysis and are written in R.

Is there any harm in allowing end-users to download these files as-is or should it be in another format?

I have a feeling that some anti-virus and search engines might mark these files as malware or spam and may give the user a bad experience on my website.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: You could take a look into [R Markdown](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-1.html) which makes it easy to compile R code into html files that can be uploaded onto your website. Or pack your files into an archive like *.zip. Your question is a little opinion based, though.

Comment: Sounds good. Do you think search engines or anti-virus will cause any issues?

Comment: The first results in common html files displayed in the browser, this should not cause any issues. Downloaded *.R files in archives will probably be scanned by anti-virus programs when users open them. You could test the behaviour e.g. online [here](https://www.virustotal.com/).

Comment: I ran the file through that tool and seems to be ok. I will go back to my folks and see if zip or HTML files are ok with them. THanks for the help!